# MKMapView - Convert long / lat to view x / y

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to map a specific point in the mapview to my view. I am using the following code, but it returns some really high and wrong numbers.

```
CGPoint annPoint = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:coord toPointToView:self.view];
```

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: are you sure that coord is currently visible?

Comment: yes it is :) is there something else i can do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. The mapview should be loaded (completly?) before i can call the convertion method.